# running record count from SplitRecord processor Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

Is there a way to get fragment index from SplitRecord processor Nifi? I am splitting a very big xls (4 mill records) into "Records Per Split" = 100000.

Now I want to just process first 2 splits, to see quality of the file and reject rest of the file.

I can see fragment index is in other split function (e.g. JsonSplit), but not in record split. Any other hack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method1:**

By using Control Rate processor we can achieve this case

**Control Rate Processor:**
[image]

By this configs we are releasing 2 flowfiles for every minute and

**Flow:**
[image]

Configure the queue expiration to like 10 sec(or lower number if you need), then the flowfiles are going to expired in the queue but first 2 flowfiles are going to be released.

**Method2:**

By using SplitText processor then use RouteOnAttribute Processor and add new property as

```
${fragment.index:le(2)}
```

By using above expression language we are only allowing only the first 2 fragment indexes.

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/122858/nifi-splittext-big-file.html) link for splitting Big File in NiFi.